# The libraries listed in bower list are not getting added to bower.json file on bower init

Tags: json, bower

When I run the command `bower list` I am getting libraries A,B,C listed in the result. But when I run `bower init` only A and B libraries are getting written to the bower.json file and not C.

Any way to debug the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C is possibly a transitive dependency (linked package) of A or B so it is not being added explicitly.
When downloading dependencies, Bower will resolve C as part of resolving A or B.